# Window("hwnd:=" & handle).Restore is causing Object not visible error

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have an application that opens up some new tabs. I'm trying to cycle through these tabs, look at them, and then close them.

```
Dim tab_children, oDesc
Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc("micclass").value = "Browser"
Set tab_children = Desktop.ChildObjects(oDesc)

Dim title, handle, cTime
For i = 0 To tab_children.Count-1 Step 1
    title = tab_children(i).GetROProperty("title")
    handle = tab_children(i).GetROProperty("hwnd")
    Window("hwnd:=" & handle).Restore
    msgbox title & ": " & handle    
Next
```

When we try to execute the .Restore, I receive an "object not visible" error. The tab that we're trying to restore is not the one that has focus, could that be the issue and if so how can we resolve it? I was under the impression that .Restore would bring that tab into focus based off of this thread, http://www.advancedqtp.com/old_forums/viewtopic.php?t=1970

The IDE I'm using is QTP, the Browser is IE.

A potential work around that I've been thinking about:
After the application opens up the new tabs, the last opened tab has focus. If we close that one, the 2nd to last has focus, all the way down to the original application's tab. Perhaps there's a way to utilize this information.

Answer (score 1):

Restore has worked for me in the past, try using Activate-

```
Window("hwnd:=" & handle).Activate
```

Edited: Just tested the following and its working on my machine-

```
'Create Browser Descriptor 
 Set oBrowser=Description.Create
 oBrowser("micclass").Value="Browser"
 'Get the child objects 
 Set oBrowser=Desktop.ChildObjects(oBrowser)
 totalcount = oBrowser.Count-1
 For i=0 to totalcount
 If Browser("micclass:=Browser", "index:="&i).Exist(0) Then 
 'get the hwnd everytime there's an iteration
 ohwnd= Browser("micclass:=Browser", "index:=" & i).GetROProperty("hwnd")

 'For debugging purposes 
 name = Browser("hwnd:="&ohwnd).GetROProperty("title")
  msgbox name

 Set oBrowser=Browser("hwnd:="&ohwnd)
 'Page descriptor 
 Set oPage=Description.Create
 oPage("micclass").Value="Page"
 Set oPage=Browser("hwnd:="&ohwnd).ChildObjects(oPage)
 For n=0 to oPage.Count-1
 If oPage(n).Exist(0) Then
 oBrowser.Close
 Exit For
 End If
 Next

 End If
 Next
```

If you want to close only a particular page you can use the GETROPREPERTY("Title") in the  If loop - If oPage(n).Exist(0)

Comment: Neither .Restore or .Activate is actually bringing to focus the wanted tab. Is that what they're supposed to be doing?

Comment: Are you opening the new tab in the same window?

Comment: Yes each tab is opened in the same window.

Comment: I have edited the answer see if it helps, in there I am getting the hwnd every time a tab closes.